# Touching "through" another Physicsbody? Swift / Spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

With the way my screen and game mechanics are set up, I have to have my top navigation bar over the top of another physics that's sort of hiding up at the top of the screen waiting to come down.

I'm adding in navigation now, and the pause menu button works fine when I don't have that sprite that's waiting to come down added up at the top, but once I add it back in, the pause button doesn't get touched anymore.

I figured maybe switching up Z position to bring the pause button to the front might work but that didn't do anything.

I have no need to ever register touch for the sprite that's falling down.

Any ideas how to make this work?

edit: Only workaround I can think of to get the navigation area free is if it's possible to start an SKshapenode at a height of 0 and then scale it to be taller forever and maintain "moving down forever" look, with an action and descale it periodically with another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if I get this correct.

If the hidden navigation node will not register touches and is not part of the game you don't need to apply `physicsBody` to the navigation.

You can leave it out or change the code to this:

```
self.topNavigation.physicsBody = nil
```

Applying `zPosition` to the nodes is a good way to 'layer' your nodes.

Comment: Sorry I probably shouldn't have added the part that said I don't need to ever touch it.

I still do need to detect collision with it so I need both the pause button and the dropping node to be physics bodies. 

Even if I have the pause button's zPosition higher than the falling node it's still not registering the touch I assume because there are 2 bodies right onto of each other

Comment: @Swiftaccnt When you say 'collision' do you mean 'touch' or collision between two nodes?

Comment: Collision between two nodes.

Comment: @Swiftaccnt You have to put one of the nodes in a category that does not collide with the other node. Have you specified the collision categories for those two nodes? If so, can you share your code?

Comment: I don't know how I wasn't getting that to work the other day. I think I tried to do that, didn't type it in right and then assumed that wasn't possible to just do it like that.

Thank you very much for your time :)